# How to get a default value when a MAX() column does not exist

Tags: mysql

So here is a sample query illustrating a simplified version of the problem I am having:

```
SELECT max_discount, product_name
FROM products
    LEFT JOIN (  
        SELECT IF(MAX(discount_percentage) IS NOT NULL, MAX(discount_percentage), 5) AS max_discount,
            product_id,
            order_id
        FROM orders
            LEFT JOIN discounts ON discounts.id = orders.discount_id
        GROUP BY order_id
    ) AS alias ON alias.product_id = products.product_id
GROUP BY alias.order_id
```

In this case, I can have multiple "discounts" (vouchers) related to the same order. But if there are multiple discounts related to a single order, I only want to actually apply the highest valued discount only. For example if you have a voucher for 50% off and another voucher for 20% off, in this case they would both be stored in the database. But I don't want to give you 70% off, I want to give you 50% off (the higher of the two). Thus, the subquery that selects the `MAX()` value.

If you don't have any discount vouchers, I still want to give you 5% off, because that's our promotion right now. Therefore the other part of the `IF` tries to set it to 5.

The problem here is that, even though my condition says `MAX() IS NOT NULL`, and I am trying to set it to 5 when it is `NULL`, it still comes up as `NULL` in the results.

When I do an `IF` condition with a simple field that can contain a `NULL` value, for example `SELECT name, IF(age IS NULL, 'Unknown', age) AS age FROM people`, then it works as expected. So why doesn't it work with a `MAX()` subquery?

Comment: I tried this in an isolated query and it works fine there. Must be something with your data or the rest of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the COALESCE function - returns the first non-null value :

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(discount_percentage), 5) ......
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the `COALESCE()` at the outer level.  But you have a bigger problem in the query, because `product_id` is not in the subquery.

```
SELECT COALESCE(max_discount, 5), product_name
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(discount_percentage) AS max_discount,
             product_id, order_id
      FROM orders o LEFT JOIN
           discounts d
           ON d.id = o.discount_id
      GROUP BY o.order_id, o.product_id
    ) od
    ON od.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY od.order_id
```

I'm still not sure this is correct, because the structure seems odd -- discounts on orders and not on products.  Aggregating by `order_id` in the outer query, but not including that in the `SELECT`.  Without sample data and desired results, it is hard to tell what you really need.